# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:Invalid index x, size is x

Tags: java, android, list, baseadapter

After 3 hours of try i decided to ask here and see if someone can provide me a solution for this error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

here is my code

```
public class ParcelAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private final Activity context;
        ParcelPOJO.Data items=new ParcelPOJO.Data();
        ParcelAdapter(Activity context, ParcelPOJO.Data items){
            this.context=context;
            this.items=items;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.getLive().size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return  0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
        class ViewHolder {
            protected TextView eventCode;
            protected TextView eventStatus;
            protected TextView eventPrice;

        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
            if(convertView==null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parcel_row, null);
            }
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.eventCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pPackage_code);
            viewHolder.eventStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pPackedStatus);
            viewHolder.eventPrice =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pPrice);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                holder.eventCode.setText(items.getLive().get(position).getCodeNumber());
                holder.eventStatus.setText(items.getLive().get(position).getStatus());
                holder.eventPrice.setText(items.getLive().get(position).getOrderStorageShowPrice());
                holder.eventCode.setText(items.getProcessing().get(position).getCodeNumber());
                holder.eventStatus.setText(items.getProcessing().get(position).getStatus());
                holder.eventPrice.setText(items.getProcessing().get(position).getOrderStorageShowPrice());
                holder.eventCode.setText(items.getPacked().get(position).getCodeNumber());
                holder.eventStatus.setText(items.getPacked().get(position).getStatus());
                holder.eventPrice.setText(items.getPacked().get(position).getOrderStorageShowPrice());
//line 119                    holder.eventCode.setText(items.getSent().get(position).getCodeNumber());
                    holder.eventStatus.setText(items.getSent().get(position).getStatus());
                    holder.eventPrice.setText(items.getSent().get(position).getOrderStorageShowPrice());
                    holder.eventCode.setText(items.getReceived().get(position).getCodeNumber());
                    holder.eventStatus.setText(items.getReceived().get(position).getStatus());
                    holder.eventPrice.setText(items.getReceived().get(position).getOrderStorageShowPrice());

                return convertView;
            }
        }
```

logcat

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
        at dedmd.dedmd.fragmentsparcel.Parcels$ParcelAdapter.getView(Parcels.java:119)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:762)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if i delete this line i get the same error but with `Invalid index 1, size is 1`

Comment: An array of size `0` can hold `0` elements. An array of size `1` can hold one element, but the first entry is at index `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This method tells the adapter how many items there are:

```
  @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.getLive().size();
    }
```

so apparently the array `items.getSent()` is not as long as the array `items.getLive()` - so the `Adapter` tries to go to a position after the end of it and it is invalid.

EDIT:

In other words, your `items` object has several arrays. One of them is `items.getLive()` and another one is `items.getSent()`

If you construct the "items" object and those two arrays have different lengths, then you will have problems. So, you need to fix how the `items` object is constructed **before** you construct your `Adapter`

EDIT 2:

If you do not control the source of your data, then you need either:

1. You need to look at your object contract (API) or get the source to create one. Having an object with sets of variable length arrays may not be what the provider intends and you have found a bug.
2. If you don't have an API or it states that you should expect possible null values, then you should be prepared for them. Maybe like this:

   if (items.getSent() != null && items.getSent(),get(poistion)) {
         holder.eventCode.setText(items.getSent().get(position).getCodeNumber());
           ...
   }

Comment: but how to fix it , how to get the specific array, is there like an if , to se wich array is called for position

Comment: the `items` array is passed as part of the constructor... you are specifying what it is, what it contains, etc. (look at you constructor: `ParcelAdapter(Activity context, ParcelPOJO.Data items)`)

Comment: i'm sorry i still can't understand , i tried to pass every List by itself , but this still  
does't solve the part with the getCount method

Comment: i can't fix the items object because it comes from a neste json ,and i coud't get it to work in other way a.k.a chnaging the 
->Items

*List<Live> live

*List<Packed> packed

Comment: if you can't control your data source, you need to check your API or check for nulls. See my edit.

Comment: i think it's a bug from the guy who made tha api , here is the source json 
http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/caZfEaQrNe?indent=2